# Dependable dropdown lists - laravel

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-4

How is it possible to make two dropdown lists depend on each other?! i.e If country X is selected, dropdown Y is visible. If country A is selected, dropdown Y is hidden and dropdown Z is visible and so on. I am creating dropdown menus as follows:

```
<div class="form-group {{($errors->has('country')) ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{Form::select('country', $countries)}}
            @if($errors->has('country'))<p class="help-block">{{$errors->last('country')}}</p>@endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{($errors->has('city')) ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{Form::hidden('city', $cities)}}
            @if($errors->has('city'))<p class="help-block">{{$errors->last('city')}}</p>@endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can this be acheived?!

Comment: Hint: JavaScript/ AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice it was that easy. Using JavaScript/Ajax as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select[name='country']").change(function() {
        //  alert($(this).val());
         if($(this).val()=="Egypt")
           {
             $("select[name='city']").show();
           }
           else
             {
               $("select[name='city']").hide();
             }
      });
});
</script>
```